# Read AccountUser's assigned to BusinessUnit in Enterprise Account

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, soap

My Business Requirement is to read the Users that are assigned to the different BusinessUnit's in our Enterprise Account. For testing purposes I'm using the PHP Library. Using the following code I'm able to read all Active BusinesUnit's:

```
// Create the retrieve request
$request = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
$objectType = "BusinessUnit"; 
$request->ObjectType= $objectType;
$request->QueryAllAccounts = true;
$request->Properties = array("ID","Description");

$filter1 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart() ;
$filter1->Property= "IsActive";
$filter1->SimpleOperator=ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::equals;
$filter1->Value=array("1");
// Attach the filter to the request
$request->Filter = new SoapVar($filter1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
                   'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

// Retrieve 
$requestMsg = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg();
$requestMsg->RetrieveRequest=$request; 
$results = $client->Retrieve($requestMsg);
```

In the next setp I want to iterate over the results and read the AccountUser assigned to each of the BusinessUnit's. Unfortunately for the AccountUser (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/accountuser/) Retrieve method the BusinessUnit can't be defined as a filter criteria. So please let me know how I can read the AccountUsers assigned to the different BusinessUnit's.

Comment: I think you have to look by accountuser and view what they are associated good to,  and not the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Setting an associated business unit is done like this:

```
  <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Options/>
     <Objects xsi:type="AccountUser" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Client>
           <ID>123610</ID>
        </Client>
        <UserID>ExampleNewUserForBU</UserID>
        <Password>password@1</Password>
        <Name>ExampleNewUserForBU</Name>
        <Email>test@bh.exacttarget.com</Email>
        <MustChangePassword>false</MustChangePassword>
        <DefaultBusinessUnit>10665829</DefaultBusinessUnit>
        <AssociatedBusinessUnits>
           <BusinessUnit>
              <ID>10665829</ID>
           </BusinessUnit>
        </AssociatedBusinessUnits>
     </Objects>
  </CreateRequest>
```

To remove an associated business unit from user:  150022 is the account that owns the user. 150011 is the user.  150023 is the BU being removed from user.

```
  <soap:Body>
    <ConfigureRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Action>assign</Action>
      <Configurations>
        <Configuration xsi:type="AccountUser">
          <Client>
            <ID>150022</ID>
          </Client>
          <ID>150011</ID>
          <BusinessUnitAssignmentConfiguration>
            <BusinessUnitIds>
              <BusinessUnitId>150023</BusinessUnitId>
            </BusinessUnitIds>
            <IsDelete>true</IsDelete>
            <IsReplace>false</IsReplace>
          </BusinessUnitAssignmentConfiguration>
        </Configuration>
      </Configurations>
    </ConfigureRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body>
```

To retrieve an assoc. BU:

```
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <RetrieveRequest>
      <ClientIDs>
         <ID>0000000</ID>
      </ClientIDs>
      <ObjectType>Account</ObjectType>
      <Properties>ID</Properties>
      <Properties>Name</Properties>
      <Properties>ParentID</Properties>
      <Properties>ParentName</Properties>
      <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
      <Properties>AccountType</Properties>
      <QueryAllAccounts>false</QueryAllAccounts>
   </RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

To retrieve BU's for a user:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>myuser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>AccountUserAccount</ObjectType>
            <Properties>AccountUser.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.AccountUserID</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.Email</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.UserID</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.ActiveFlag</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.IsActive</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.CustomerID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>AccountUser.AccountUserID</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>7351261</Value>
            </Filter>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            <Options>
                <Client>
                    <ID>7230402</ID>
                </Client>
            </Options>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

To retrieve users for a BU:

```
    <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>AccountUserAccount</ObjectType>
            <Properties>AccountUser.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.AccountUserID</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.Email</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.UserID</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUser.ActiveFlag</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.IsActive</Properties>
            <Properties>Account.CustomerID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>Account.Id</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>150029</Value>
            </Filter>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            <Options>
                <Client>
                    <ID>150022</ID>
                </Client>
            </Options>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: While old these sir are golden nugget payloads. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The AssociatedBusinessUnits property on the AccountUser object is not retrievable.

See response from ExactTarget representative here: https://code.exacttarget.com/question/how-remove-account-users-all-associated-business-units

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a retrieve on the `accountUser` object, and filter on each `accountUser` by the `AssociatedBusinessUnits`.  This will give you a listing of what you are looking for.