# AccountUser in SSJS not fetching any data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I've issue with retrieving 'AccountUser' object via SSJS. I've created a cloud page in a BU to which I've access to and my account is an 'API user' account - so, I figured I should get a response.
My goal here is to get all the users and their permission sets & roles and further retrieve all permissions of all the roles (for audit purpose). I couldn't find any report that does this and I'm that API can be used to retrieve permission sets.

```
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
  try {
    /* Begin Retrieve Request */
    var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "AccountUser");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ActiveFlag");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "AccountUserID");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Name");
    /* Filter Response */
    var sfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "Property", "Name");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "SimpleOperator", "like");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp, "Value", "matheswaran_kanagarajan");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", sfp);
    /* Invoke Retrieve */
    var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
    Write("Rows --> " );
    Write(Stringify(rows));
  }
  catch(e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this on a child BU? The AccountUsers exist at the parent BU level so it would not be expected to return any results in a child BU.

Try running your code on the parent BU and you should get a response.

There's more useful info in the below article:

[Read AccountUser's assigned to BusinessUnit in Enterprise Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28753/read-accountusers-assigned-to-businessunit-in-enterprise-account/101098)